# 3 blocks inline with bootstrap and dynamic data (for loop)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to render my data into 3 blocks next to each other

I tried this code :

```
{% for row  in rows %}
    <div class="col-md-4" >  
        {% for column, cell in row.items %}
              {{ cell }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The blocks are displayed next to each other.. but they are very close .. I want to add a space between the blocks so I added a margin of `15px` as style of the `div` . This change pushed the third div to the next line.
I changed `col-md-4` to `col-md-3` but the blocks were very disordered.

Is there a way to have a space between blocks without pushing the third div to next line?

Comment: `padding` instead of `margin`

Comment: I has the background of div is colored ..so padding is not a great solution for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to give `background color` to `div` nested inside the columns of grid.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col-xs-4 {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px; /*Required spacing here */
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.inner-div {
  padding:15px;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="inner-div">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="inner-div">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="inner-div">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```